# How would you loop a command using discord.js v.12?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So I have this code here? `client.channels.cache.get("823609622488154143").send( animeEmbed) }, 1 * 1);`

This code is attached to a embed I am sending that my bot is fetching from a reddit site, I would like this command to continuously run but I am having difficulties figuring out how I can loop this. Can this be done through an async run or differently.

Comment: I think using setTimeout is a good solution to this. You run a function every n minutes/seconds. Answer if you need a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since you don't want to send it nonstop, you are looking for something like this:

```
function startTimer(time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //the code that sends the embed
    }, time)
}

startTimer(60000) //one minute interval
```

What this does is, it runs the function that sends your embed every one minute to the channel you specified. You can change the time by replacing the `60000` with another number (1000 is one second).

I hope this is what you are looking for. Have a nice day :)